# Matplotlib: Getting subplot position values (hspace, wspace, ..)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have changed the spacing of my subplots successfully with the Subplot Configuration Tool (accessible in the figure window), now I would like to actually get the values of the properties I just set: `hspace`, `wspace` etc.

Where can I find these?

I tried `plt.getp(plt.axes())`, along with other objects as argument to `getp` but have had no luck in finding them so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `fig.subplotpars`

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

fig, axes = pyplot.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

print(fig.subplotpars.hspace, fig.subplotpars.wspace, sep='; ')
```

And that prints:

```
0.5; 0.2
```